# Getting "503 Rate Limit Exceeded" from Xtify Push API

Tags: android, push-notification, xtify

I'm sending push notifications through Xtify 1.3 API and at top loads receiving in response an HTML message instead of JSON:

```
<html><body><h1>503 Rate Limit Exceeded</h1></body></html>
```

Currently I'm sending the requests using 20-thread QUARTZ setup.

Could somebody help me figure out how to tune my API client to avoid looking as an attacker to the HTTP server or whatever part of the service is pushing me out?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Actually they are limiting Connection Rate, it means that you need to keep them open as it is possible with HttpComponents HttpClient [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is 5 simultaneous connections per IP as described at the bottom of this page:

http://developer.xtify.com/display/APIs/Push+API+2.0

You should either limit your concurrency to 5 or if you have access to multiple IP addresses you could just segment across them to stay within the limit.

However, it would probably just be easier just to reach out to Xtify and request that the limit be raised for your application.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, the number of failures has dropped significantly, but I still need to reach out to the support.